# How to solve a JSON parse error: 'no implicit conversion of String into Integrer'?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, twitter, typeerror

I'm learning the Twitter search API for an ongoing project. I can connect and receive a "200" response. The following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
require 'json'

=begin
  __code for oauth and creating response__
=end

def print_results(tweets)
  tweets.each do |tweet|
    puts tweet
  end
end

if response.code == '200' then
  tweets = JSON.parse(response.body)
  print_results(tweets)
end
```

prints this result to the screen:

```
statuses
{"metadata"=>{"result_type"=>"recent", "iso_language_code"=>"es"}, "created_at"=>"Mon Dec 02 11:10:53 +0000 2013", "id"=>407466896939044864, "id_str"=>"407466896939044864", "text"=>"Y \"Thérèse\" me recordó sobremanera a \"Madame Bovary\". A mi parecer ambas igual de insulsas.", "source"=>"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>", "truncated"=>false, "in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil, "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil, "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil, "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil, "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil, "user"=>{"id"=>159480381, "id_str"=>"159480381", "name"=>"our last autumn", "screen_name"=>"RoxyVarlow", "location"=>"Valencia", "description"=>"Perdóname por lo que pueda hacer cuando no te recuerde.", "url"=>"http://t.co/AjyasSdTXb", ......
```

But when I try to parse it with JSON, and extract the text of the twit, either with:

```
def print_results(tweets)
  tweets.each do |tweet|
    puts tweet['statuses'][0]['text']
  end
end
```

Or with:

```
puts tweet['text']
```

I receive an error:

```
rb:17:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I extract the text of the tweet from the response?

Comment: We need a sample of the raw JSON. Without that it's hard to tell how your code is mishandling the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code solved my issue:

```
if response.code == '200' then
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)
  result['statuses'].each do |result|
  puts result
  puts "#{result['user']['screen_name']} : #{result['text']}"
end
```

it appears that the response.body is wrapped in 'statuses' so i needed to iterate over each member of statuses in order to access the tweet information.